# how to control if use password encryption in Spring Security authentication or not

Tags: spring, authentication, encryption

We are developing a web application which will be delivered to several clients with a deployable WAR file. They just need their technician to customize their data source. Now there comes a requirement. Some clients want to encrypt password but others dont.  I tried:

```
   <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
   <bean id="MyUserDetailsService" class="com.xxx.xxxx.listener.MyUserDetailsService"/>
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider   user-service-ref="MyUserDetailsService">
           <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

It works. I know if I remove

```
 <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
```

then the app will not apply password encryption in the authentication process. But we do not want our clients to make such change by themselves. We want to control it programmatically based on a system setting in DB or from a webpage. I have no idea how to implement it. Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

**Updates**
 Thank jhadesdev for his idea. I solved it by creating a subclass and overriding the encodePassword method. I use ShaPasswordEncoder at this moment because I need to encode a large number of existing password in PostgreSql db.

```
public class CustomerShaPasswordEncoder extends ShaPasswordEncoder {

    @Autowired
    protected AdminDao adminDao = null;

    public CustomerShaPasswordEncoder() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomerShaPasswordEncoder(int strength) {
        super(strength);
    }

    @Override
    public String encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt) {

        SecuritySetting ss = adminDao.getSecuritySetting();
        if ((ss == null || ss.getEncryptPassword() == null || ss
                .getEncryptPassword() == false)) {
            return rawPass;
        } else {
            return super.encodePassword(rawPass, salt);
        }
    }

}
```

But I dont know how to load the parameter to a static variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible for example create a subclass of `BCryptPasswordEncoder` named `MyCustomEncoder`, and override the encode method. There it's possible to decide to apply or not the encoding depending on the content of a database parameter.

The database parameter that determines if the encoding should be applied can be lazy loaded from the database the first time that it's cached via a DAO that reads from a table containing this type of parameters.

The database parameter can then be stored in a static variable to avoid having to load it each time.